# Keras Deploy for Tensorflow.js Usage

Tags: firebase, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow.js

I need to be able to deploy a keras model for Tensorflow.js prediction, but [the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/manage-hosted-models) only seem to support a TFLite object, which [tf.js cannot accept](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/991). Tf.js appears to accept JSON files for loading [(loadGraphModel() / loadLayersModel() )](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#loadGraphModel), but not a keras SavedModel (.pb + /assets + /variables).

How can I attain this goal?

*Note for the Tensorflow.js portion:* There are a lot of pointers to the [tfjs_converter](https://huningxin.github.io/tfjs-converter/), but the closest API function offered to what I'm looking for is the [loadFrozenModel()](https://huningxin.github.io/tfjs-converter/#native-file-system) function, which requires both a `.pb` and a `weights_manifest.json`. It seem to me like I'd have to programmatically assemble this before before sending it up to GCloud as a keras SavedModel doesn't contain both (mine contains .pb + /assets + /variables).

This seems tedious for a straightforward deployment feature, and I'd imagine my question only hits upon common usage of each tool.

**What I'm looking for is a simple pathway from Keras => Firebase/GCloud => Tensorflow.js.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I understand your confusion but you have half part ready.
So your keras model has the following files and folders if I understand correctly:

```
saved_model.pb
/assests
/variables
```

This is enough to convert the keras model to tensorflow.js model.
Use the converter script in the following manner. Make sure you have the latest version of `tfjs`. If you do not have the latest version, try creating a `virtual environment` and install latest `tfjs` otherwise it will disrupt your `tensorflow` version.

```
import tensorflowjs as tfjs
import tensorflow as tf

model=tf.keras.models.load_model('path/to/keras/model')

tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, 'path/where/you/will/like/to/have/js/model/converted')
```

Once you have converted the model you will receive following files for `js` model.

```
model.json
something.bin
```

You will have to host those files using a webserver and just make it available for loadLayersModel API something like this:

```
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(
     'location/of/model.json');
```

That is it and you have converted the model from Keras to Tensorflowjs and uploaded as well in js.

I hope my answer helps you.

Comment: What about Custom models?


`NotImplementedError: Saving the model to HDF5 format requires the model to be a Functional model or a Sequential model. It does not work for subclassed models, because such models are defined via the body of a Python method, which isn't safely serializable.`